# Какие существуют альтернативы библиотеки утилит GLUT?

Tags: opengl, sdl, glut

Я пытаюсь изучить OpenGL и только что обнаружил, что ***библиотека утилит GLUT*** устарела. Я уже знаком с [***мультимедийной библиотекой SDL***](https://www.libsdl.org/), и мне кажется что это хорошая альтернатива. Должен ли я использовать мультимедийную библиотеку SDL для разработки игр с OpenGL или есть лучшие альтернативы?

Я новичок в разработке графических приложений особенно игр, поэтому мало что знаю о современном состоянии дел. А хотелось бы в них разобраться.

*вопрос является вольным переводом [этого вопроса](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23652/what-alternatives-to-glut-exist), связан он с тем что часто сталкиваюсь с позицией (как я думаю) что от рисовкой занимаются "шейдеры", а не "конвейер". Возможно я просто очень плох в "жаргонизмах" либо я просто чего то недопонимаю :3.*

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> Я только что обнаружил, что библиотека утилит GLUT устарела.

Вот что происходит, когда вы принимаете первый встреченный вами ответ, вы получаете неверную информацию GLUT 3.7 использовать не следует, но [FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) полностью обратно совместим с ним.

Однако ваш вопрос касается другого вопроса. GLUT и его аналоги не подходят для создания игры . Он не дает вам контроля над основным циклом, а он вам действительно нужен в игре ([FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) имеет способ управлять основным циклом, но он очень не удобный). GLUT предназначен для написания графических демонстраций. Это очень важно при тестировании новых графических эффектов, поэтому при необходимости это должно быть в вашем наборе инструментов. Но ваш основной игровой код никогда не должен его использовать.

[GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/) - это легкая альтернатива GLUT, ориентированная на игры. Он обеспечивает базовую поддержку для вещей, помимо создания окна OpenGL. Он позволяет вам вводить данные, загружать изображения в виде текстур и многое другое.

[SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/), [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) и [Allegro 5](https://liballeg.org/index.html) - это мультимедийные инструменты. Они могут создавать окна OpenGL, но делают *гораздо* больше. Они обеспечивают полную поддержку ввода, звука и других вещей, необходимых для создания игры. Если вы делаете игру, любой из них - хорошая отправная точка. Мне лично нравится Allegro 5, но это всего лишь мое предвзятое отношение к хорошей документации и чистому API.

Также стоит упомянут что все производители ААА игр не используют ничего из предложенного. В общем, они не используют ничего с открытым исходным кодом. Они могли бы, но если они собираются использовать библиотеку, они бы предпочитают использовать поддерживаемую библиотеку. Есть некоторые исключения, такие как ODL или Bullet.

---

GLUT - это не только библиотека, но и программный интерфейс приложения (API). Исходная библиотека действительно устарела. API - это другое дело, это было неплохо для начала, ему просто нужны доработки для преодоления ограничений и удовлетворения новых потребностей. Основная текущая реализация - [FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/), которая поддерживается и не устарела.

Отмеченная выше проблема с «управлением главным циклом» некорректна. С новыми версиями GLUT вы можете лучше контролировать игровой цикл (если это важно для вас). Ограничение было исправлено функцией `glutMainLoopEvent()`. Это и другие ограничения рассматриваются здесь:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Toolkit

> «С новыми версиями GLUT вы можете лучше контролировать игровой цикл
> (если это важно для вас)». Это игра, поэтому да, это важно для вас.
> Кроме того, glutMainLoopEvent вряд ли является хорошим способом
> управления основным циклом. Он по-прежнему использует модель,
> управляемую событиями, для подачи вам данных, а не модель опроса, где
> вы получаете данные, которые вам нужны, когда вы этого хотите.

утверждает Николай Боласов.

> Я должен утверждать, что модель, управляемая событиями, более
> эффективна, чем опрос, если только вы не опрашиваете данные,
> хранящиеся на основе событий (что вполне нормально). Опрашивать
> системные ресурсы следует осторожно.

оперирует Ингемар Немцов.

---

Qt поддерживает OpenGL. Взгляните на [Open Inventor](https://www.openinventor.com/) и подумайте, есть ли смысл для вас сразу перейти к 3D API более высокого уровня.

---

Примечания переводчика , на практике заметил что 2Д и 3Д примитивы спокойно можно рисовать в Qt (начиная от Qt 5 ) за правила от рисовки (конвейер) ответить не могу, но для моих задач хватало мощности и я на "глаз" не заметил отличий.Также упомяну что в Qt 6 проделана большая работа именно в сторону 3Д графики и визуализации.

Answer (score -1):

для более "высокого" уровня использую графический пакет [Urcho3d](https://urho3d.io/)